# Javascript : Seems like typeof doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to set a Value in a javascript object only when it is not set. My (test) function looks like:

```
var test = function(){
    this.value = {};

    this.setValue = function(seperator, newValue){
        console.log((this.value[seperator] === "undefined"));  //Why both times false?
        if(typeof(this.value[seperator] === "undefined")){
            this.value[seperator] = newValue;
        }else{
            //noop
        }
        console.log(this.value[seperator]);
    }
}
var blubb = new test();

blubb .setValue("foo","bar");
blubb .setValue("foo","notme");
```

in the js console it returns

```
false
bar
false
notme
```

Can someone tell me why both time my test of "undefined" told me that is not defined?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) in JS is not a string, it's a property of *global* object and you comparing by type using `===`.

`===` will compare not only values but their types too:

```
1 === "1" // false
1 == "1"  // true
```

Try this:

```
console.log(( typeof this.value[seperator] === "undefined"));
```

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator transforms variable type to string and only then you can check if your variable is equal to string `undefined`.

In your second piece of code:

```
if(typeof(this.value[seperator] === "undefined")){
```

you use `typeof` operator outside of the variable so your code first checks if `this.value[seperator] === "undefined"` then it returns `false` to you and then you check by "typeof false", it will return `boolean` for you.

In final step your code converts to:

```
if( "boolean" ){
```

And this is always `true` as string is not empty.

Comment: yay, thank you! that was it! :)
but why ff and chrome told me by console.log(typeof(typeof(aaa))) that the returning undefined is a string?

Comment: and why stackoverflow thinks that I can not get a correct answer in 10 minutes?

Comment: @Hansinger because first time it checks for `typeof(aaa)` and return string `"undefined"`, then you try to check `typeof "undefined"` and it returns `"string"`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

`"undefined"` !== `undefined`

Check for `undefined` instead.

```
> var foo = { foo: 'foo' };
> foo['bar']
undefined
> typeof(foo['bar'])
"undefined"
```

Also note that `typeof(this.value[seperator] === "undefined")` means `typeof(boolean)` as it'd first evaluate your expression (`this.value[seperator] === "undefined"`) and then get the type of that.

You probably meant `typeof(this.value[seperator]) === "undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are in the wrong place in this line:

```
if(typeof(this.value[seperator] === "undefined")){
```

You're doing the typeof of `(this.value[seperator] === "undefined")` - that's a boolean condition (will return `true` or `false`) so I'd expect `typeof` to give you `"boolean"`. Then your `if` statements condition is the string `"boolean"` which, since it's not zero length, is considered true in JavaScript.

What you wanted is:

```
if((typeof this.value[seperator]) === "undefined") {
```